# Python Indentation Error Issue

Tags: python

I'm getting this problem on a simple test on a Python file,

```
class Prueba(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.position = 0


    def build_message(self, signal):
        message = self.position
        message = message | (0b1<<signal)
        s = bin(message)
        s = s[2:len(s)]
        s = (16-len(s))*'0' + s

        s0 = s[0:len(s)/2]
        s1 = s[len(s)/2:len(s)]
        s0 = s0[::-1]
        s1 = s1[::-1]
        s_final = int(s0 + s1, 2)
        return s_final

    def motor_activation(self):
        rospy.logwarn("Preparing motor to start...")
        if(self.drive_status[MC] == False and self.drive_status[READY] == False and self.drive_status[BRAKE] == False and self.drive_status[ERROR] == False):
            rospy.sleep(1)
            ####### Avtivate FG_R #######
            message = self.build_message(FG_R)
            self.setBrModbusValue(2, message)

            ##Wait a little
            rospy.sleep(1)

            ####### Avtivate FG_E #######
            message = self.build_message(FG_E)
            self.setBrModbusValue(2, message)
```

Im getting this message when trying to execute it with ipython:

```
message = self.position
      ^
IdentationError:expected an indented block
```

Comment: In which lines?

Comment: mix of tabs & spaces?

Comment: can you edit your code with an editor which is NOT notepad++? tabs and spaces are problematic unless some setting is fixed.

Comment: line 8:

message = self.position

Comment: I use sublimeText

Comment: OT, but that `if` condition is horrible. Consider changing it to `if not all((self.drive_status[MC], self.drive_status[READY], self.drive_status[BRAKE], self.drive_status[ERROR]))`:

Comment: @DeepSpace: you just introduced a bug because you thought that version was more readable. He tests that they're all false, you test that they're not all true.

Answer (score 0):

This must be an issue of tabs mixed with spaces.

You can convert all the tabs into spaces by changing some settings in editor you are using.

In case of sublime text :
Preferences -> settings-User

Try saving this as Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings

```
{
    "tab_size": 4,
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true
}
```